# I am getting connection TimeOutError while using curl

Tags: curl

I am trying to access this `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/m1guelpf/plz-cli/main/install.sh | sh -` but everytime I run I am getting the following error

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

I have notices I am getting this error when I tried to use curl previously also , so this not specific to this .

I am using ubuntu 20.04 lts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://florahuo.medium.com/failed-to-connect-to-raw-githubusercontent-com-port-443-connection-refused-how-to-fix-6a5920a188f4

You have to manually add the host using  the command

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

In my case I had to add the following ip address

```
185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
```

and it worked

I followed the steps mentioned in this article and it fixed my issue

Comment: While this may be useful information, just a heads-up that link-only answers are [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413510/11810933), and often even deleted by Moderators on Stack Exchange sites since [they aren't considered complete "answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  It's best to include the relevant portions of the link, or at least a summary, in your answer.  Thanks!